# I am in group root and cannot use synaptic or sudo

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-netbook, sudo, users

I do not know the root password. I am only in group root. How do I add myself to other groups?

I am getting this error on trying to open root terminal:

> Failed to run
>   /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator as user
>   root.
>
> The underlying authorization mechanism
>   (sudo) does not allow you to run this
>   program. Contact the system
>   administrator.

Answer (score 2):

As you do not have root access anymore, you cannot add yourself to the admin group. To do this, you need to boot in recovery mode to get root permissions.

1. Restart your computer, and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> (for GRUB2) for showing the boot menu
2. Select "Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.xx-xx-generic (recovery mode)"
3. Pick "Root shell" from the recovery menu
4. Add user `abc` to the `admin` group by running: `usermod -a -G admin abc`. The `-a` switch causes the group `admin` be added to current groups, instead of replacing the current groups.
5. Reboot your system by running `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a terminal and typing

```
 sudo bash
```

It will become a root terminal.

Comment: `abc@ubuntu:~$ sudo bash`  
    `[sudo] password for abc:`   
    `abc is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`  
    `abc@ubuntu:~$`

Comment: @abc, how comes you're in the root group and not in the sudoers? Anyway, the only solution I see is: boot a live distro and manually edit /etc/groups to add your username after the last `:` of all the lines referring to groups you'd like to be in (for instance, `adm:x:4:abc`)

Comment: I did a usermod without -a option. By live distro you mean a live CD ?

Comment: @abc: yep. or usb key.

Comment: Your user should not be in the group `root` or `sudo` or whatever. It just needs to be in `admin` for `sudo` to work (unless you changed things in `/etc/sudoers`).